# How to get the next and previous row in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql-5.7

I have a table `employees` as,

```
id   name   startDate   endDate
1    John   2013-8-9    2020-10-30
5    Nick   2011-6-7    2020-10-2
7    Pick   2012-6-9    2019-10-12
```

I have list of employees sorted by start date. Now clicking on a record, I also want to get the next and prev row based on the starting date.
Like in the above example, the array is sorted as 1,7,and 5, so when i click on 7, I also need to get 1 as previous and 5 as next. Please can you help, I got the record by `id`, checked the date greater than `startDate` of that `id` then I ordered by `statDate` in ASC order and limit the record by one.

Comment: what mysql version do you have? Some CTE supported versions of MariaDB and MySQL-8.0 might provide a way to do this neatly.

Comment: I'm using mysql v 5.7

Comment: Does the column `startDate` have a **unique** constraint? If you have repeated values, how do you sort them?

Comment: What should happen, if there is no previous (or next) row? No row or a row of `NULL`s?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a subquery counting the number of row with a lower start date or with an equal start date but lower ID. Based on that, you can select the row where this count is equal to the count the row with the desired ID has and the previous or next row by subtracting or adding 1.

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.name,
       x.startdate,
       x.end
       FROM (SELECT t1.id,
                    t1.name,
                    t1.startdate,
                    t1.enddate,
                    (SELECT count(startdate)
                            FROM elbat t2
                            WHERE t2.startdate < t1.startdate
                                  OR t2.startdate = t1.startdate
                                     AND t2.id < t1.id) rn
                    FROM elbat t1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    -1
                    FROM dual
                    WHERE (SELECT (SELECT count(startdate)
                                          FROM elbat t2
                                          WHERE t2.startdate < t1.startdate
                                                 OR t2.startdate = t1.startdate
                                                    AND t2.id < t1.id)
                                          FROM elbat t1
                                          WHERE t1.id = ?) = 0
             UNION ALL
             SELECT NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    (SELECT count(startdate)
                            FROM elbat t1) + 1
                    FROM dual
                    WHERE (SELECT (SELECT count(startdate)
                                          FROM elbat t2
                                          WHERE t2.startdate < t1.startdate
                                                 OR t2.startdate = t1.startdate
                                                    AND t2.id < t1.id)
                                          FROM elbat t1
                                          WHERE t1.id = ?) = (SELECT count(startdate)
                                                                     FROM elbat t1)) x
       WHERE x.rn IN ((SELECT (SELECT count(startdate)
                                      FROM elbat t2
                                      WHERE t2.startdate < t1.startdate
                                            OR t2.startdate = t1.startdate
                                               AND t2.id < t1.id)
                                      FROM elbat t1
                                      WHERE t1.id = ?) - 1,
                      (SELECT (SELECT count(startdate)
                                      FROM elbat t2
                                      WHERE t2.startdate < t1.startdate
                                            OR t2.startdate = t1.startdate
                                               AND t2.id < t1.id)
                                      FROM elbat t1
                                      WHERE t1.id = ?),
                      (SELECT (SELECT count(startdate)
                                      FROM elbat t2
                                      WHERE t2.startdate < t1.startdate
                                            OR t2.startdate = t1.startdate
                                               AND t2.id < t1.id)
                                      FROM elbat t1
                                      WHERE t1.id = ?) + 1)
     ORDER BY x.rn;
```

Untested as no sufficient DDL or DML was provided!

Replace the `?` by the ID you want to query. If you don't need or want rows of `NULL`s, if there is no previous or next row remove the `UNION ALL`ed subqueries. Speaking of `NULL`s: As it stands, it won't work on rows where the start date is null.

Answer (score 0):

For "previous", you can use:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.startDate > (select e2.startDate from employees e2 where e2.id = 7)
order by e.StartDate asc
limit 1;
```

For "next":

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.startDate < (select e2.startDate from employees e2 where e2.id = 7)
order by e.StartDate desc
limit 1;
```

If you need both, you can `union all` these together.